# Multi-channel wav file handling with C

Tags: c, audio, wav

I want to make a tool that can play a `wav` file. 
Luckily, I found a good example that works fine playing mono or stereo wav files. 
But what I really need is a tool that can play multi-channel wav files.

I found that the multi-channel wav file is format tag is 65534 (means extensible wave format) and this format has more header information, so I just added the waveformatexx my code:

```
waveFormatExt.Format.cbSize = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE) - sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);
waveFormatExt.Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = riffFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec;
waveFormatExt.Format.nBlockAlign = riffFormat.nBlockAlign;
waveFormatExt.Format.nChannels = riffFormat.nChannels;
waveFormatExt.Format.nSamplesPerSec = riffFormat.nSamplesPerSec;
waveFormatExt.Format.wFormatTag = riffFormat.wFormatTag;
waveFormatExt.Format.wBitsPerSample = riffFormat.wBitsPerSample;
waveFormatExt.dwChannelMask = extFormat.dwChannelMask;
waveFormatExt.SubFormat = extFormat.SubFormat;
waveFormatExt.Samples.wSamplesPerBlock = extFormat.wSamplesPerBlock;
waveFormatExt.Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = extFormat.wValidBitsPerSample;

waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &waveFormatExt, (DWORD)WaveOutProc, (DWORD)lpWaveData, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
{
    dwDelay = (riffFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8) * riffFormat.nSamplesPerSec * riffFormat.nChannels;
    _tprintf(TEXT("bytesPerSec = %d\n"), dwDelay);
    dwDelay = riffData.dwChunkSize / dwDelay;
    _tprintf(TEXT("TotalSec = %d (%02d:%02d)\n"), dwDelay, (dwDelay / 60), (dwDelay % 60));

    waveHeader.lpData = (LPVOID)lpWaveData;
    waveHeader.dwBufferLength = riffData.dwChunkSize; 
    waveHeader.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
    waveHeader.dwFlags = 0L;
    waveHeader.dwLoops = 0L;
    waveHeader.dwUser = 0;
    waveHeader.lpNext = NULL;
    waveHeader.reserved = 0L;

    waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    {
        waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        Sleep(dwDelay * 1000 + 1000);
    }

    waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
```

I use a structure called waveformatex when the formattag is 1, and use a playback structure similar to the above code, and the above code is the code for playback when the file is a multi-channel wav file.

No matter what method I use, I want to play a multi-channel wav file.
Can anyone help with this problem..?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I would be much easier to help you if you have provided a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far to make it work.

Comment: I do not know why direct show is in the title. I have never written..